# Highchart separate range selector date from and date to

Tags: input, highcharts, range, selector

Is there a way to separate the input range from and to in Highcharts?

[image]

Jsfiddle demo would be appreciated. Thanks you in advance bro.

http://jsfiddle.net/77vrjpj4/1/

Comment: What do you mean with "separate"? Give a left/right padding/margin?

Comment: I want to split out the input date range selector. It meant that I create two input box and control the functionality the same as highcharts input range selector.

Comment: First you give us a fiddle we can work on!

Comment: here it is, [link]http://jsfiddle.net/77vrjpj4/1/

Comment: In case when you have a html inputs and you fill these fields by dates, then you can call setExtremes action on xAxis. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

Comment: @SebastianBochan could you please kindly provide me a demo? thanks you in advance!

Comment: In docs you have an setExtremes example, Instead of static values catch inputs by  parseFloat($('#inputid').val()) and use in setExtremes.